# Getting word count for all files within a folder

Tags: php, file, text-processing

I need to find word count for all of the files within a folder.

Here is the code I've come up with so far:

```
$f="../mts/sites/default/files/test.doc";

// count words
$numWords = str_word_count($str)/11;
echo "This file have ". $numWords . " words";
```

This will count the words within a single file, how would I go about counting the words for all files within a given folder?

Comment: 0% and no upvotes? You obviously don't care, why should we?

Comment: @Mike: the problem he is far to be alone to do that!

Comment: @Lavanya, Mike B has a point.  Maybe you just don't understand how this site works, but you've asked 19 questions and not accepted any answers.  At the very least that's extremely rude.

Comment: hey i dont know how to vote sorry

Comment: Seriously? The SO interface is about as basic and intuitive as it gets and after 19 questions, twice as many comments, and countless additional visits you can't figure out how to vote or accept questions?

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
$array = array( 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt' );
$result = array();
foreach($array as $f ){
 $result[$f] = str_word_count(file_get_contents($f));
}
```

and using the dir

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    $result = array();
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Files:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
       if($file == '.' || $file == '..')
           continue;
       $result[$file] = str_word_count(file_get_contents('/path/to/files/' . $file)); 
       echo "This file {$file} have {$result[$file]} words";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Lavanya, you can consult the manual of [readdir](http://us.php.net/readdir), [file_get_contents](http://us.php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: @Rob: that's a good remark but he didn't say that was word file ... let's way his comment.

Comment: Hmm you're correct, I guess I saw the words "word" and "doc" in his post and my brain put them together...

Comment: let's wait ... ouch I am tired!

Comment: Hi really good code u sent i am thanking u very much...reagards lavanya ks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the **doc** files are plaintext and don't contain additional markup, you can use the following script to count all of the words in all of the files:

```
<?php
$dirname = '/path/to/file/';
$files = glob($dirname.'*');
$total = 0;
foreach($files as $path) {
    $count = str_word_count(file_get_contents($path));
    print "\n$path has $count words\n";
    $total += $count;
}
print "Total words: $total\n\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *nux than you can use `system('cat /tmp/* | wc -w')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$words = str_word_count(file_get_contents($filepath))` to get the word count of a *text file*, however this won't work for word docs.  You'll need to find a library or external program that can read the .doc file format.